# Scan for users of networks

Tags: networking

If I am in a room where several people are using devices to connect to different networks, how can I scan for them? (for the users)

They are not necessarily logged in the same wifi as me.

I know that I can find networks with WICD (or through other means), but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 3 tools that might work:

- [zenmap](http://nmap.org/zenmap/)
- [nmap](http://nmap.org/)
- [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Kismet](http://www.kismetwireless.net/) does the trick if the networks are unprotected.

> Kismet is an 802.11 layer2 wireless network detector, sniffer, and intrusion detection system. Kismet will work with any wireless card which supports raw monitoring (rfmon) mode, and (with appropriate hardware) can sniff 802.11b, 802.11a, 802.11g, and 802.11n traffic. Kismet also supports plugins which allow sniffing other media such as DECT.